# Observable's doOnError correct location

Tags: java, rx-java

I am kind of new to `Observers`, and I am still trying to figure them out. I have the following piece of code:

```
observableKafka.getRealTimeEvents()
        .filter(this::isTrackedAccount)
        .filter(e -> LedgerMapper.isDepositOrClosedTrade((Transaction) e.getPayload()))
        .map(ledgerMapper::mapLedgerTransaction)
        .map(offerCache::addTransaction)
        .filter(offer -> offer != null)  // Offer may have been removed from cache since last check
        .filter(Offer::isReady)
        .doOnError(throwable -> { 
              LOG.info("Exception thrown on realtime events");
          })
        .forEach(awardChecker::awardFailOrIgnore);
```

`getRealTimeEvents()` returns an `Observable<Event>`.

Does the location of `.doOnError` matters? Also, what is the effect of adding more than one call to it in this piece of code? I have realised I can do it and all of them get invoked, but I am not sure of what could be its purpose.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it does. `doOnError` acts when an error is passing through the stream at that specific point, so if the operator(s) before `doOnError` throw(s), your action will be called. However, if you place the `doOnError` further up, it may or may not be called depending on what downstream operators are in the chain.

Given

```
Observer<Object> ignore = new Observer<Object>() {
    @Override public void onCompleted() {
    }
    @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
    }
    @Override public void onNext(Object t) {
    }
};
```

For example, the following code will always call doOnError:

```
Observable.<Object>error(new Exception()).doOnError(e -> log(e)).subscribe(ignore);
```

However, this code won't:

```
Observable.just(1).doOnError(e -> log(e))
.flatMap(v -> Observable.<Integer>error(new Exception())).subscribe(ignore);
```

Most operators will bounce back exceptions that originate downstream.

Adding multipe `doOnError` is viable if you transform an exception via `onErrorResumeNext` or `onExceptionResumeNext`:

```
Observable.<Object>error(new RuntimeException())
.doOnError(e -> log(e))
.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<Object>error(new IllegalStateException()))
.doOnError(e -> log(e)).subscribe(ignore);
```

otherwise, you'd log the same exception at multiple locations of the chain.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation on the `onErrorResumeNext()`. It's going to be very useful.

Comment: How to log the exception in case of `Observable.just(1).doOnError(e -> log(e))
.flatMap(v -> Observable.<Integer>error(new Exception())).subscribe(ignore);` do you know @akarnokd?

Comment: Specify the `onError` handler in `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 6):

the `doOn???` methods are there for side-effects, processing that doesn't really is your core business value let's say. Logging is a perfectly fine use for that.
That said, sometimes you want to do something more meaningful with an error, like retrying, or displaying a message to a user, etc... For these cases, the "rx" way would be to process the error in a `subscribe` call.

`doOnError` (and the other `doOn` methods) wraps the original `Observable` into a new one and adds behavior to it (around its `onError` method, obviously). That's why you can call it many times. Also one benefit of being able to call it anywhere in the chain is that you can access errors that would otherwise be hidden from the consumer of the stream (the `Subscriber`), for instance because there's a retry down in the chain...

Comment: Sorry Simon, I'm not sure I got the explanation about the benefit of multiple `doOnError`. Could you elaborate that a little bit more?